# Possible to connect an Apple Thunderbolt Display to a Thunderbolt 3 dock via an adapter?

Tags: display, adapter, usb-c, thunderbolt

I have an Apple Thunderbolt Display at my desk, which I currently use with a Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 adapter to connect to a newer MacBook Pro via USB-C. As the display cannot provide power over its Thunderbolt 2 port, I'm using a separate USB-C power adapter to provide power to the laptop via one of its other USB-C ports.

I recently obtained a ThinkPad that does have Thunderbolt 3 ports... but only two of them. If I power the laptop and connect it to an external display as I'm currently doing, I'm left with no USB-C ports left.

I know there are docks out there that connect to a laptop via Thunderbolt 3 and also provide Thunderbolt 3 ports themselves. With one of those docks, is it possible to connect the Thunderbolt Display to one of the dock's Thunderbolt 3 ports via a TB2 -> TB3 adapter to free up one of the ports on the laptop? In other words, do the Thunderbolt 3 ports on such a dock behave identically to the Thunderbolt 3 ports on the laptop itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have a similar setup where I am using my MBP 16" 2019 Intel model with a dock. You will need the following things.

A thunderbolt dock. The one I am using is Anker 577 Thunderbolt Docking Station (13-in-1, Thunderbolt 3).
You will also need a Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter which is available in Apple stores, I was not able to find any cheaper alternative to this adapter.

Connect the Apple Thunderbolt Display to the Anker Dock via the Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter. The dock has its own power supply and is ready to provide upto 85W of power to its connected laptop with a Thunderbolt 3 wire which comes with the dock.

With a single wire that goes to your laptop you can connect to your Thunderbolt Display as well as you can charge your Laptop.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get to keep the apple Thunderbolt display functions? like brightness control and volume control with the anker dock?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).